# Automated testing for an Android app's behavior from a factory reset state

Tags: android

I'm attempting to create an automated testing framework for an Android app, and it is of particular importance to test is the behavior of this app when it is installed on an otherwise factory reset device.

However, it is proving difficult to do this in an automated way, since performing an actual factory reset will disable USB debugging and force me to interact with the device between each testing run.  Ideally I would want to run the app hundreds of times from a factory reset state across multiple devices, using slightly different simulated user behavior each time. Doing so manually would obviously be an enormous waste of time.

Once usb debugging is active it is trivial to install and run the app, then perform a factory reset on the device using scripts.

Is there a way to achieve a near-factory state without disabling the debug bridge?  Device rooting is out of the question.  I was wondering if there's a way to "fake" a factory reset by clearing out all the data and settings (minus usb debugging being enabled).

Apologies for the vagueness.

Comment: Why not just clear the app data from Settings > Application > App Info for the app > force stop & clear data. Might just accomplish the same thing you are after.  A clean state of the application to be tested.

Comment: Unfortunately the app is altering things on the device besides its own state through some special permissions, so in this case resetting the state of the app itself wouldn't be enough.  I could definitely see it as being part of a larger solution, though!